# Kinect vs. PSDK5.0 Registration Speed

Tags: ros, kinect, primesense, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have 2 Kinects and a PSDK 5.0, I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 and the latest debian-based install of Diamondback. Both of the Kinects work fine with openni_camera (of the openni_kinect stack) generating either /camera/depth/points or /camera/rgb/points outputs at high speed. However, with my PSDK, I can only seem to get reliable depth point clouds. Issues are:

- Only the VGA 30hz mode works for XYZRGB clouds, and at only about 8hz.
- If I connect to /camera/rgb/image_color while viewing only the XYZ cloud I can get a 30hz update rate on the image and the XYZ cloud, so it doesn't appear to be an issue with USB bandwidth.
- Turning on registration, even without a subscriber on /camera/rgb/points appears to significantly slow things down.

Any thoughts? This machine is a quad-core i7 with 8GB of RAM, and the registration runs fine on the Kinect devices...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9855/kinect-vs.-psdk5.0-registration-speed/) by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13902 on 2011-04-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-06-17**:
Has this sorted itself out?

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-05-01**:
I haven't gone and tried the OpenNI directly -- that's next on my list. With the old NI stack, I had similar results (actually, it seemed less reliable than the current results).

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-05-01**:
Have you tried the old NI stack or just standard OpenNI drivers? Perhaps the openni_kinect stack doesn't really support the PSDK5.0 so well or has a regression of some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This seems to have been fixed in more recent versions of the driver.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0